# how to do sum of value on button? winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, sum

I have a checklist like this:

```
 checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new MyData { ID = 1, Name = "test1", Value = 5 });
```

and I have a button that will compile all checked items into a list with total sum of value:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        foreach (MyData data in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {               
           listBox1.Items.Add(data.Name);
        }           
    }
```

but I don't know how to write the sum of data.Value, for example if i wanted to display the sum of checkeditems value in a label or textbox. please help me understand

Comment: If you want to sum Value then use the loop to look at the property Value.

Comment: `checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<MyData>.Sum(...)`?

Comment: i tried that code above before and it gave me a context error when i put it on a button

Comment: how do i use the foreach loop to look at value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ways to do it:

```
int total = 0;
foreach (MyData data in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{               
   listBox1.Items.Add(data.Name);
   total += data.Value;
}
```

If you have a List type you can use LINQ

```
   from cr in db.TableName
               group cr by cr.ID into g
               select new {Total = g.Sum(x=>x.Value)};
```